# How nginx rewrite and proxy? http://sa.com/rabbitmq/api/#/queues/%2F/somequeue

Tags: nginx, proxy, rabbitmq

I try to use a single domain to proxy several programs like this:

`http://sa.com/rabbitmq/ --->  http://localhost:15672/
http://sa.com/zabbix/ ---> http://localhost:10000/`

and my conf is blow:

`location /rabbitmq {
   rewrite /rabbitmq(.*) $1 break;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:15672;`

It works well until I click a queue name to watch the detail,
which url is as the title said:
`http://sa.com/rabbitmq/api/#/queues/%2F/somequeue`

an 404 error occured, I saw an request in dev-tools of chrome:

`http://rabbitmq.testing.gotokeep.com:15672/api/queues/%2F/dailyNewLike?lengths_age=60&lengths_incr=5&msg_rates_age=60&msg_rates_incr=5`

this request returned 404.

I guess that when `rewrite` processed, the uri was decoded (.../%2F/... -> ...///...) and the extra slashes will be removed...

Is my guess right? Is there a solution?

Comment: Not clear. Title states that `%2F` in hash part of the url. That part never reach server (i.e. nginx).

Comment: @AlexeyTen sorry, I updated the information.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way (or even any way) to prevent nginx from decoding URIs like this. The best I could imagine is to keep prefixes in url and modify yout apps to work with that prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is good, but no, the real problem is that nginx converts `%2F` into `%252F` (`%` -> `%25`).

`%2F` is `vhost` name (`/`). I don't found the real solution for this problem,  and my workaround was to use other `vhost` name which do not contains `/` symbol (e.g. `pool1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use $request_uri to prevent nginx decode the uri.
use conf like below

```
location /rabbitmq {
    if ($request_uri ~* "/rabbitmq/(.*)") {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:15672/$1;
    }
}
```